# Jtable returns Error without message onload. Response returns 200

Tags: json, jquery-jtable

I'm newbie with jtable. Today i've tried to set up my grid with data from the server. But when i call

```
jtable('load')
```

I see 200 result in browser and my json which is correct but jtable returns Error popup:[image]

Here's the js part of code:
[image]

Fields are named in the same way as in json. Does anybody know what's wrong with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Response should be in such format:

```
{
 "Result":"OK",
 "Records":[
  {"PersonId":1,"Name":"Benjamin Button","Age":17,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
  {"PersonId":2,"Name":"Douglas Adams","Age":42,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
  {"PersonId":3,"Name":"Isaac Asimov","Age":26,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
  {"PersonId":4,"Name":"Thomas More","Age":65,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"}
 ]
}
```

Documentation: http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Actions